# Laptop to TV connectivity

Tags: laptop, tv

How do you you get signal from HPdv7 laptop to TV (Sony Bravia).  I connected HDMI between both, but no computer signal - just TV shows.  It worked for me instantly with a different TV.

Comment: You tried pushing the "Input" button, right?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the desktop > Screen Resolution and click Detect..

If your tv is listed but grayed out select it and choose to extend your display onto the tv.

Set the resolution and also choose to mirror the display if you want to.

Here's a screenshot of a screen with more than one display:

[image]

You can also press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to manage display connectivity.